# Read/write value with pipe

Tags: c, unix, pipe, pipeline

I have a problem with this code, how i can send a number betwen this procces, like 1 send to 2, 2 send to 3, and 3 send to 1, and everytime decreases with an i*10, like first time 10, second time 20, ...30 , ... until the number is negative, and then stop the program?
I make this code, but i have a problem, the value of number 'a', dont decrease like a=1342 in 1, decrease 20, and in 2 need to have 1322, it's start from 1342.
Here is my code:

```
 #include <sys/types.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int i=0;
int main()
{
    pid_t p;
    int a=1324;
    int fd[2];
    int fd1[2];
    pipe(fd);
    p=fork():
    if(p < 0)
    {
        perror("Fork error");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if(p==0)
    {
    while(1)
    {
        close(fd1[1]);
        read(fd1[0],&a, sizeof(int));
        printf("Procces 2, a is %d.\n",a);
        wait(1);
        close(fd[0]);
        a=a-(i*10);
        i++;
        write(fd[1],&a,sizeof(int));
    }
    }
    else
    {
    p=fork();
    if(p < 0)
    {
        perror("Fork error");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(p > 0)
    {
        while(1)
        {
            close(fd1[1]);
            read(fd1[0],&a, sizeof(int));
            printf("Procces 1, a is %d.\n",a);
            wait(1);
            close(fd1[0]);
            a=a-(i*10);
            i++;
            write(fd1[1],&a,sizeof(int));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while(1)
        {
            close(fd[1]);
            read(fd[0],&a, sizeof(int));
            printf("Procces 3, a is %d.\n",a);
            wait(1);
            close(fd1[0]);
            a=a-(i*10);
            i++;
            write(fd1[1],&a,sizeof(int));
        }
    }
}
return 1;
```

}

- I want to print like this:
- Process 1, a is 1324 (decrease 0 and send to 2)
- Process 2, a is 1324 (decrease 10 and send to 3)
- Process 3, a is 1314 (decrease 20 and send to 1)
- Process 1, a is 1294 (decrease 30 and send to 2)
- ...
- But the program si some like this:
- Process 1, a is 1324
- Process 2, a is 1324
- Process 3, a is 1324
- Process 1, a is 1314
- ...

Someone can tell me where is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Proper identation of the code would definitely help everyone.

Comment: Code that *compiles* would be equally helpful. `fd[1[)` isn't valid C. . Neither is `p=fork():`. And `wait()` doesn't take an `int` parameter.

Comment: Sorry, i have linux installed on a virtual machine, and i can't copy from linux to windows, so i write manually...

Comment: That sucks. ah well. anyway, I think the likelihood of success will be exponentially better if `fd1` is actually a set of **pipes** and not some indeterminate values. (i.e. you never `pipe[fd1]`). But that is no silver bullet, as your `close()` calls should not be in your loops. Do yourself a favor. review how pipes work, how `fork()` works, and write a **two** process version of this before trying to sync three together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this isn't what you're trying to do its damn close. You want to clearly identify which pipes are use for writing and reading **for each process**. The easiest way I've found to do that is by labeling the indexes with macros. For example. a sequence of six pipes (three pairs):

```
//  This arrangement means;
//
//  P1 listens to P2, writes to P3
//  P2 listens to P3, writes to P1
//  P3 listens to P1, writes to P2

#define P1_READ     0
#define P2_WRITE    1
#define P2_READ     2
#define P3_WRITE    3
#define P3_READ     4
#define P1_WRITE    5
#define NUM_PIPES   6
```

This makes the client code **substantially** easier to understand:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 1324;
    int i=1;

    int fd[NUM_PIPES];

    // create pipes
    if (pipe(fd) < 0 || pipe(fd+2) < 0 || pipe(fd+4) < 0)
    {
        perror("Failed to create pipes");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // fork P2 child process
    if (fork() == 0)
    {
        close(fd[P1_READ]);
        close(fd[P1_WRITE]);
        close(fd[P3_READ]);
        close(fd[P3_WRITE]);

        while (read(fd[P2_READ], &a, sizeof(a)) == sizeof(a))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "P2: (i==%d) received %d\n", i, a);
            if ((a -= (i++ * 10)) < 0)
                break;
            write(fd[P2_WRITE], &a, sizeof(a));
        }

        // close our other pipes
        close(fd[P2_READ]);
        close(fd[P2_WRITE]);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    // fork P3 child process
    if (fork() == 0)
    {
        close(fd[P1_READ]);
        close(fd[P1_WRITE]);
        close(fd[P2_READ]);
        close(fd[P2_WRITE]);

        while (read(fd[P3_READ], &a, sizeof(a)) == sizeof(a))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "P3: (i==%d) received %d\n", i, a);
            if ((a -= (i++ * 10)) < 0)
                break;
            write(fd[P3_WRITE], &a, sizeof(a));
        }

        // close our other pipes
        close(fd[P3_READ]);
        close(fd[P3_WRITE]);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    // parent process. close the pipes we don't need
    close(fd[P2_READ]);
    close(fd[P2_WRITE]);
    close(fd[P3_READ]);
    close(fd[P3_WRITE]);

    // kick things off with a write of the first value
    write(fd[P1_WRITE], &a, sizeof(a));

    // same code as before
    while (read(fd[P1_READ], &a, sizeof(a)) == sizeof(a))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "P1: (i==%d) received %d\n", i, a);
        if ((a -= (i++ * 10)) < 0)
            break;
        write(fd[P1_WRITE], &a, sizeof(a));
    }

    // close the pipes we no longer need
    close(fd[P1_READ]);
    close(fd[P1_WRITE]);

    wait(NULL);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The resulting output looks something like this:

```
P3: (i==1) received 1324
P2: (i==1) received 1314
P1: (i==1) received 1304
P3: (i==2) received 1294
P2: (i==2) received 1274
P1: (i==2) received 1254
P3: (i==3) received 1234
P2: (i==3) received 1204
P1: (i==3) received 1174
P3: (i==4) received 1144
P2: (i==4) received 1104
P1: (i==4) received 1064
P3: (i==5) received 1024
P2: (i==5) received 974
P1: (i==5) received 924
P3: (i==6) received 874
P2: (i==6) received 814
P1: (i==6) received 754
P3: (i==7) received 694
P2: (i==7) received 624
P1: (i==7) received 554
P3: (i==8) received 484
P2: (i==8) received 404
P1: (i==8) received 324
P3: (i==9) received 244
P2: (i==9) received 154
P1: (i==9) received 64
```

Toy with the numbers (`i`, `a`,) to your leisure. Hope it helps.